# Should I specify my header include path in the source code, or as a project option?

Tags: c++, c, headers, include, path

Basically, I am asking, whether my code should say

```
#include “../libs/src/my_lib.h”
```

or

```
#include “my_lib.h”
```

with a complier option of

```
-I ../libs/src/
```

I feel (reasonably strongly) that the former is preferable, because:

- it is independent of build system
- it specifies exactly which “my_lib” is meant, in case there are several.

My current project uses the latter style, with `-I` in the project file, saying that:

- we will never change build system, compiler or platform
- every file has a unique name

That actually sounds reasonable, so I wonder if I am just being influenced by opinion, or whether there is any technical reason (***not*** an opinion) to prefer one approach over the other.

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate to view your build system as separate from your project. Your Makefiles (or equivalents) are part of the code. With that, your question could be reframed as “should I put the information about library location into one central place, or spread it across the whole project?” → see Caleth's answer :)

Comment: I agree with "I don't think it's appropriate to view your build system as separate from your project" (+1). I was thinking of re-use, particularly cross platform. I somewhat like your rephrasing about "central vs strewn", but that loses a few details, like being able to know which "inc.h" is meant, if there are several of that name in the project (bad practise, I know)

Answer (score 9):

In my current workplace, various projects are using [boost](https://www.boost.org/) versions ranging from 1.60 to 1.66, and at appropriate times we move those forward. It's much simpler to repoint the project includes to a different folder and leave *all* the `#include`s alone.

These projects are cross platform, we are using multiple compilers. Each compiler has some equivalent of `-I ../libs/src/`, and we use qmake to coordinate them all.

As amon notes in a comment,

> I don't think it's appropriate to view your build system as separate from your project. Your Makefiles (or equivalents) are part of the code.